# What is the difference between ActivePython and Python?

Tags: python, activepython

I am new to Python. I am supposed to launch an application and perform some tasks on the application from Python.

I found Python from python.org and ActivePython from activestate.com.

What is the difference between them? Which should I install?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does ActivePython exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352528/why-does-activepython-exist)

Answer (score 21):

ActiveState is an open source company which bundles Python with some additional packages and makes it available for variety of platforms. Sometimes they support platforms which the standard Python distrubution does not. For example AIX comes to my mind.

Many beginners to python on Windows have this doubt when they start with Python. ActiveState provides a bundle of Python executable with Python Windows Extensions and PEPS and Dive into Python ebook as package, so that you will have a good solution.

Technically there is not any difference between Python from activestate.com and from python.org if it available for download for your platform.

And yes, you can install Python 2.7.1 as it is latest supported version in 2.x series.

Comment: But be sure to read ActiveState's licensing terms first to make sure your use of their version is acceptable.

Comment: hey thanks a lot...will definitely check the license terms of The active state.....is it necessary to install active python.. after installing python 2.7.1....

Comment: user578131- I think you missed the point, activepython is just one of the company which ships python 2.7.1 ( python.org hosts and ships it too)

Comment: How does ActivePython compare to Anaconda?

Answer (score 4):

One key difference is that ActivePython comes with a binary package manager called [PyPM](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/) that makes it easier to install packages like numpy, scipy and lxml.

Comment: Fast forward to 2018: "PyPM ... will be going offline permanently on November 1, 2018"

Answer (score 3):

ActiveState usually only provides the latest versions of their packages for free, if you need an older version for whatever reason you will have to sign up for one of their paid accounts. Python.org seems to have all their old versions available for download.

Answer (score 2):

An important difference is that ActiveState Python is proprietary software and, if you put it in production, they can force you into subscription software fees and sue you if you don't pay.  Their sales people have been tracking down heavier users and companies with more users and threatening them into unexpected payments.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Python 3.9, ActiveState has a new approach. Developers can create their own builds of Python 3.9 for free on the ActiveState Platform - and these builds are pure Open Source.

There still are proprietary limits - but these are based on how much an individual or organization uses the ActiveState Platform and not on the licensing of the software.

Full disclosure: I work for ActiveState.