# python win32com shell.SHFileOperation - any way to get the files that were actually deleted?

Tags: python-2.7, pywin32, shfileoperation

In the code I maintain I run across:

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
# ...
result,nAborted,mapping = shell.SHFileOperation(
        (parent,operation,source,target,flags,None,None))
```

In `Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32comext\shell\` (note win32comext) I just have a `shell.pyd` binary.

1. What is the return value of shell.SHFileOperation for a deletion (`operation=FO_DELETE` in the call above) ? Where is the code for the shell.pyd ?
2. Can I get the list of files actually deleted from this return value or do I have to manually check afterwards ?

EDIT: accepted answer answers Q1 - having a look at the source of `pywin32-219\com\win32comext\shell\src\shell.cpp` I see that `static PyObject *PySHFileOperation()` delegates to [SHFileOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which does not seem to return any info on which files failed to be *deleted* - so I guess answer to Q2 is "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActiveState Python](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) help contains `SHFileOperation` [description](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/shell__SHFileOperation_meth.html):

> ### shell.SHFileOperation
>
> int, int = SHFileOperation(operation)
>
> Copies, moves, renames, or deletes a file system object.
>
> ---
>
> Parameters
>
> operation : SHFILEOPSTRUCT
>
> Defines the operation to perform.
>
> ---
>
> Return Value
>
> The result is a tuple containing int result of the
>   function itself, and the result of the fAnyOperationsAborted member
>   after the operation. If Flags contains FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE, returned
>   tuple will have a 3rd member containing a sequence of 2-tuples with
>   the old and new file names of renamed files. This will only have any
>   content if FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION was specified, and some filename
>   conflicts actually occurred.

Source code can be downloaded here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/ (pywin32-219.zip)

Just unpack and go to `.\pywin32-219\com\win32comext\shell\src\`

Comment: Thanks - could you add a link to active python ? Plus those `FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE` maps are valid when moving files - I am interested in delete - I want to avoid a `for fil in toDelete: if file.exists(): updateSomeUI(fil)` loop after I call the `shell.SHFileOperation(FO_DELETE)` (which may raise (?))

Comment: For those who like me don't know wahtr AS Python is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1352541/281545

Comment: Did you try `shutil.rmtree(...)`? It has `onerror` parameter to set handler if not deleted.

Comment: source is a file or a list of files (not a tree) + those who wrote this want apparently the windows native dialogs - accepting though cause the link to the source partially answers Q2 too :)